# Rails app keeps trying to connect to "development .rb" file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, development-environment

So this is a confusing one. I'm not sure where I went wrong, but I did somewhere, and given the problem, it seems like it should be a simple fix.

For the first time, my Rails app is crashing every time I launch it in the terminal. It crashes because it is trying to connecting to "development .rb" - there is a space between the end of the word and the period. And every time it launches, it creates a file called "development .log".

I don't actually have a "development .rb" file, so I'm not sure why it's trying to connect to it.

So somewhere in my code I have to tell it to only connect to development.rb (no space). Any thoughts on how I can do this?

```
19:44:43 web.1  | started with pid 28696
19:44:44 web.1  | I, [2013-05-16T19:44:44.514474 #28696]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
19:44:47 web.1  | You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your development  environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/development .rb
19:44:47 web.1  | /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/RailsApps/bptest/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from config.ru:4:in `require'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from config.ru:1:in `new'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `eval'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn.rb:44:in `block in builder'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/unicorn-4.6.2/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
19:44:47 web.1  |   from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
19:44:47 web.1  | exited with code 1
19:44:47 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

Comment: what command are you using to start the or what does your Procfile look like?

Comment: Looks like the problem comes from the fact that Rails is waiting for an adapter, probably in your database file e.g. mysql or mysql2 for example.

Comment: please post config/database.yml

Comment: You probably have a `RAILS_ENV` environment variable with a space at the end of it.  Look for something like `export RAILS_ENV="development "` somewhere in your config.  Also try this at a shell prompt to confirm: `echo $RAILS_ENV | od -c`; look for a trailing space in the octal dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, everyone. For my case, Jim Stewart had it exactly right. In my application's .env file, I had a space directly after "RACK_ENV=development" - I must have opened that file and pressed the spacebar at some point recently. I simply deleted that extra space and everything is working perfectly now.